# Cassandra spark connector joinWithCassandraTable on field with differents name

Tags: scala, cassandra, apache-spark, datastax-enterprise, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm looking to make a join on a RDD and a cassandra table which have not the same name for the same key
ex (simplified):

```
case class User(id : String, name : String)
```

and

```
case class Home( address : String, user_id : String)
```

If  would like to do :

```
rdd[Home].joinWithCassandraTable("testspark","user").on(SomeColumns("id"))
```

How can I precise the name of the field on which the join will be made.
And I don't want to map the rdd to have only the right id because I would like to join all values after the joinWithCassandraTable.

Comment: can you change the name on the rdd? Otherwise, look at how joinWithCassandraTable works under the hood and do it yourself manually. https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/88ef5da544c4a27ac08fdcfd46c6a401f3c032d6/spark-cassandra-connector-java/src/main/java/com/datastax/spark/connector/japi/RDDJavaFunctions.java#L89

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the "as" syntax just like in a select to change the mapping of what the joined columns are.

An example

```
sc.cassandraTable[Home]("ks","home").joinWithCassandraTable("ks","user").on(SomeColumns("id" as "user_id")).collect
```

Will map the "id" column from the user table to the "user_id" field from the `Home` case class.

Comment: Thank for answer. Did joinWithCassandraTable is also suitable for small result dataset ( less than 10 row ) ? And is it possible to have case class (udt) as join key?

Comment: It will work on small datasets, whether or not this will be performent is dependent on your partition length. If the udt can be read by the connector it should work.

Comment: A join query or normal spark join will do a sort merge based shuffle which requires reading the whole thing table. Join with Cassandra table uses only the partition keys to lookup rows. DSE has an optimization which can convert some sql joins to join with Cassandra but this is not in the OSS version

Answer (score 1):

You could try changing the column name when you read in the Cassandra table so that it matched the RDD field you want to join on:

For example:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSQLContext
val sc: SparkContext = ...
val cc = new CassandraSQLContext(sc)
val rdd: SchemaRDD = cc.sql("SELECT user_id AS id, <other columns> from testspark.user WHERE ...")
```